# Regex to increase a string by one only (consecutive numbers)

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I use Notepad++, and I need a regular expression to match consecutive numbers only

Example:

```
verses 3-4
verses 11-12
verses 26-27
```

so the regex finds these matches, and *not* lines like: verses 3-9, or verses 26-32.. etc.

I use the \d+, but don't know how to increase the same one by just one.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that with Regex.

Comment: You could do all possible matches like `(\d*1-\d*2|\d*2-\d*3|\d*3-\d*4|...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions match *text*, not *numbers*. Therefore, you can't do this with a regex alone (unless you spell out all possible combinations). You need a scripting language that converts the matched texts to integers and compares those.

For example, in Python:

```
for potentialmatch in re.finditer(r"(\d+)-(\d+)", mytext):
    if int(potentialmatch.group(1)) + 1 == int(potentialmatch.group(2)):
        # Match found
```

Comment: That won't really help for Notepad++ or most other text editors, since you can search for a regex, but usually not use any programming language to filter results :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, short of using a regex that encompasses all such options.

You can generate one, though:

```
(1..99 | %{"$_-$($_+1)"}) -join '|'
```

in PowerShell yields a regex that will match everything from 1-2 to 99-100.